# How to load file not using hashicorp/template in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, hashicorp

Apple M1 chip doesn't support `hashicorp/template` and which result in the below error

```
╷
│ Error: Incompatible provider version
│ 
│ Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
│ 
│ Provider releases are separate from Terraform CLI releases, so not all providers are available for all platforms. Other versions of this provider may have different
│ platforms supported.
╵
```

I'm looking for the alternative for data "template_file"

```
data "template_file" "nginx_ingress_controller" {
  template = file("${path.module}/nginx_ingress_controller.yaml")
}

resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress_controller" {

  name             = "my-platform"

  values = [
    data.template_file.nginx_ingress_controller.rendered
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a `.terraform.lock.hcl` in the same directory? If so, was it created on another type of OS (Windows/Linux)?

Comment: This was basically replaced by the `templatefile` function a few years ago. You can give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing can be accomplished by using the [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function that is natively available in terraform `v0.12` and above.

If you replace your definition above with something like this:

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress_controller" {

  name             = "my-platform"

  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/nginx_ingress_controller.yaml", {})
  ]
}
```

In addition, since it doesn't look like you're actually using the templating aspect of the templatefile functionality (note the empty map passed as the second argument to the templatefile function), you could probably get away with just using the [file](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/file) function to render a file's contents as a string.

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx_ingress_controller" {

  name             = "my-platform"

  values = [
    file("${path.module}/nginx_ingress_controller.yaml")
  ]
}
```

Finally, if you don't have any other places that require the `template_file` provider, you can remove `hashicorp/template` from your required providers.

Comment: Quick command to remove reference from state file after replacing template_file with templatefile and template_cloudinit_config with cloudinit_config if both or either is used.

`terraform state list | grep -E -i -w 'template_file|template_cloudinit_config' | xargs terraform state rm`

**The above works for states stored locally or in cloud.**